# NodeJS request response occasionally getting Parse Error message

Tags: node.js

I have a simplified call like this:

```
var post_req = http.request(post_options, function(post_result) {
            post_result.setEncoding('utf8');
        post_req.on('error', function(err) {//failfolder
            res.writeHead(400, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
            res.end(retdata);

            console.log(
                    "\x1b[37m", "Remote IP", "\x1b[32m", clientIp + ' ',
                    "\x1b[37m", 'Proxied apicall to:', "\x1b[32m", cfg.email_api + path + "\n",
                    "\x1b[31m", 'API call failed with reason:', err.message + "\n",
                    "\x1b[37m", 'API response:', "\x1b[32m", retdata + "\n",
                    "\x1b[37m", 'Stack:', "\x1b[32m", err.stack + "\n",
                    "\x1b[37m", 'Headers:', "\x1b[32m", post_req.rawHeaders + "\n",
                    "\x1b[37m", "=================================");
        });
```

The `stack` part of the above console.log prints the below

we get occasionally **Parse Error**:

```
API response:
  Stack:  Error: Parse Error
    at Error (native)
    at Socket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:377:20)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:559:20)
```

We don't know what kind of issue we should locate.

After upgrading to **v12.11.1**

```
API call failed with reason: Parse Error: Expected HTTP/
  API response:
  Stack:  Error: Parse Error: Expected HTTP/
    at Socket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:456:22)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:308:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:289:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:223:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:182:23)
  Headers:  undefined
```

Comment: Which version of Node.js? Perhaps a bug in an older Node.js version. Or the webserver that you talk to does not always return a complete and valid HTTP response, that Node.js cannot interpret correctly. Check with Wireshark or try to reproduce with another tool, for example Postman.

Comment: It happens on 6 and 10, tomorrow will try 12. I couldn't reproduce, it runs on a high speed API, and it happens occasionally every 4-5 minutes, and on retry it goes well.

Comment: I would try to capture the HTTP traffic using Wireshark or tcpdump for 4-5 minutes. Run it as closely to the Node.js process as possible, preferably on the same machine. When an incident occurs, find the offending HTTP response and see if there is something wrong with it, like malformed headers or an incomplete response.

Comment: @rveerd on v12 we get this `Parse Error: Expected HTTP/`

Comment: Looks like an incomplete or malformed HTTP response message. Try to use a network or protocol sniffer (Wireshark, tcpdump) to confirm this.

Comment: @rveerd I have some new info. The error kicks in, but the request completes. So we have a on->error and also on->end with successful request. That is really strange.

Comment: you still have this issue?  I saw it when running jest tests on an express app, but upgraded to 12.16.3 and not seen it since (though it was quite rare before so not up to 5 sigma yet!).

Comment: I will try again

Comment: I had the `Parse Error: Expected HTTP/` in my unit tests recently (using `supertest`) and it turned out that the problem was incorrect value for `Content-Length` header. Maybe that could be a hint in your case.

Comment: @Rafael can you post your comment as answer

Comment: sure, I can post it as an answer. It took me a while to figure out the root cause. If that helped you, then I'm glad I shared this hint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've encountered the `Parse Error: Expected HTTP/` recently when unit testing using `supertest`. It turned out that the problem was incorrect value for `Content-Length` header. If the header value was less than the real content size, then `supertest` failed the test with the mentioned error.
That could be a hint for your case.

Comment: This was really helpful for me. If you're in the same place, make sure you aggregate all of your content before writing it with e.g. `res.write`, then set your `Content-Length` header.